# How to Deal with Mass Combat

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, gm-techniques, combat

I recently had a session where the party was on board a boat (Smugglers) with a crew size of 40 which got into a fight with a boat (Royal Marines) with a crew size of 60.

Obviously I didn't put the whole crew into combat, I limited it to 10 Smugglers and 10 Marines (plus the captain of each boat).

Including the party, this meant there were 26 people on the initiative sheet, 22 of which were NPCs under my control fighting against each other. This meant that most of the fight was spent with the party watching me playing with myself.

Obviously this is unacceptable.

What would be a better way to deal with this? My job is to make the players have fun and not sitting around bored while I figuratively jerk off, but I also want to impress upon them the scale of a large battle.

I am willing to accept any and all suggestions, no matter how crazy (including incorporating other game systems).

Comment: Is this PF or 3.5e, or a mashup of both?

Comment: Possibly, a duplicate of [Combat rules for large battles](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/432)

Comment: Likely a duplicate of [How do I quicken / sum up larger (but not army-scale) d20/DnD3.x combat?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/7293). ghosthardware, does that Q&A answer your question?

Comment: @Shalvenay PF, but 3.5 combat is close enough that I figure I would add the tag as well.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie That more-or-less answers my question. I'm open to more suggestions, but I'm satisfied enough to close the question as soon as I'm able.

Comment: Cool. We'll mark it as a duplicate so that it stays useful, becoming another way for searchers to find the existing answers.